# Parsing XML with ElementTree with self closing tag error

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have some xml that I am parsing with `ElementTree` and I don't believe that the structure/content other than the line I have provided of the xml is relevant so I have omitted it.

I am parsing it as: `Rwy.find('Special').text`

And when the xml line is: `<Special>                        </Special>`

Then everything is parsed as expected, however when the xml line is instead:

`<Special/>`

It produces the error: `TypeError: must be str, not NoneType` which leads me to believe there is some difference because of the self closing tag instead of the previous example with the closing tag.

How can I properly parse the element with the self closing tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White space is significant in XML.

Compare:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
>>> s = '<test><Special>   </Special></test>'
>>> tree = et.fromstring(s)
>>> tree.find('Special')
<Element 'Special' at 0x000001A7E9B154F8>
>>> tree.find('Special').text
'   '
```

versus:

```
>>> s = '<test><Special/></test>'
>>> tree = et.fromstring(s)
>>> tree.find('Special')
<Element 'Special' at 0x000001A7E9B1F638>
>>> tree.find('Special').text
>>>
```

The first returns `str`.  The second returns `None`.  There is no `.text` content in the self-closing tag.

Check the return value of `.text` before you use it.